# how to count object array by status filter using angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

Need help to solve this problem, i need output from count how many user with status = y.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "jonathan",
        "status": "y"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "hendra",
        "status": "n"
    }
]
```

how to count by status == y in angular? please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its an array of objects, you can use array.filter and length,

```
var result = yourArray.filter(t=>t.status ==='y').length;
console.log(result);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myData = [{
"id":"1",
"name":"jonathan",
"status":"y"
},
{
"id":"1",
"name":"hendra",
"status":"n"
}];
var result = myData.filter(t=>t.status ==='y').length;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: im so happy solve by your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
const array = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'jonathan',
    status: 'y',
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'hendra',
    status: 'n',
  },
];

const totalStatusY: number =  array.reduce(
  (nbStatusY, user) =>
    user.status === 'y' ?
      nbStatusY + 1 :
      nbStatusY,
    0
);
```